# Redirect rule case insensitive

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-speling

I have URL rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

When this URL is called: `http://example.com/suyash`

It internally calls `http://example.com/sites/suyash` but keeps the URL as `http://example.com/suyash` only. Please note that the folder `sites/suyash` actually exists

The issue I am facing is that when I call a URL: `http://example.com/Suyash` (Uppercase) it shows a 404 error.

When I use the mod_speling module and add the following to the code:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

and now when I call `http://example.com/Suyash` it changes the URL to `http://example.com/sites/suyash`

How do I get it to only change URL from `http://example.com/Suyash` to `http://example.com/suyash`?

Comment: it happens as soon as i add CheckSpelling on and hit the url with wrong case

Comment: it is possible that since the folder sites/suyash exists and not sites/Suyash the CheckSpelling on code redirects the url\

Comment: but the code: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [NC,L] only rewrites the url normally

Comment: ok what is the behavior when your turn off `CheckSpelling`

Comment: when CheckSpelling is off then wrong case shows 404 error

Answer (score 0):

mod_speling will *redirect the browser* in order to fix spelling, there's no way to avoid this. The only thing I can think of is to try proxying the request internally by using the `P` flag. You'll need to make sure you have mod_proxy loaded. I haven't tested this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [NC,L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep `CheckSpelling` off.

And then have your rule like this:

```
CheckSpelling Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -f [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [L]
```